# redirect not sending to view when called from APIcontroller

Tags: c#

This is my code below

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]EnquiryInfo webEnquiry)
{
    //some code
    if (result.ToString() == "true" || result.ToString() == "True")
    {

        //UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder("~/ApplicationForm/Success");
        //String url = "http://localhost:65041/ApplicationForm/Success";
        //System.Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        //return Redirect(uri);
        return Redirect("~/ApplicationForm/Success" );
    }
 }
```

Applicationform is a different controller which has the view Success.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Saikat. Do you see any messages in the Output window?

Answer (score 0):

A `Redirect` (the are you are using) points to a url not a file/action.

You could use a `RedirectToAction` and point to the controller and action by name.

Comment: What error is it showing, I cannot help without the Information

Comment: Redirecttoaction is not a method in apicontroller